# Is LittleBigPlanet 2's vertical output resolution 1080 or 720?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

The original *LittleBigPlanet*'s vertical output resolution was 720.  I'm curious what the sequel's resolution is.  I'm hoping Media Molecule bumped it up to 1080.

Comment: Uhhh... If you are trying to ask if it's 720p or 1080p... fairly sure it's 1280x720 and then 1920x1080

Comment: Thanks.  I took out references to the horizontal resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to [Gamespot forums](http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/action/littlebigplanet2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-57753968&pid=954843), a somewhat recent thread says that it will run up to 720p, but no 1080i or 1080p.

However, in-game, it will by default not take up the whole screen (keeping the aspect ratio) if you are playing on a 1080p monitor/TV. You can scale the video up to fit to the whole screen by hitting start in-game and going through the settings. So, in a sense, it can be 1080p though the quality may be reduced oh so slightly that you probably won't notice it.

Comment: Just to confirm, I own the game, and the box says 480P•720P.